# What is wrong with my solution for a limit?

Tags: calculus, limits

The answer is $-1$, but I get $1$. What did I do wrong?

$$\lim_{x\to -\infty} \frac{\sqrt{x^2+1}}{x+1}=\lim_{x\to -\infty}\sqrt{\frac{x^2+1}{(x+1)^2}}$$
$$=\lim_{x\to -\infty} \sqrt{\frac{x^2+1}{x^2+1+2x}}=\lim_{x\to -\infty} \sqrt{\frac{1+\frac{1}{x^2}}{1+\frac{2}{x}+\frac{1}{x^2}}}=1$$

Comment: your first equality is true up to a sign.

Comment: Notice $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$. That's the problem

Comment: To fix, rewrite the numerator instead: $\sqrt{x^2+1}=|x|\sqrt{1+1/x^2}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your first equality, the denominator is in fact equal to 
$$
\sqrt{(x+1)^2}=|x+1|
$$
which loses the sign of your expression.

And a quick solution while I'm here:
For very small $x$, adding or subtracting a constant won't matter, so your limit is equivalent to 
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow -\infty}\frac{\sqrt{x^2}}{x}=\lim_{x\rightarrow -\infty}\frac{|x|}{x}=-1
$$
since $x$ is negative near $-\infty$ and so $|x|=-x$.